# Facebook Comments plugin "Warning: This Message Contains Blocked Content"

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments, warnings, message

I have fb comments social plugin installed in a client's website.

2 days ago an error message was shown to all users trying to post a comment, including myself(Admin).

Warning: This Message Contains Blocked Content
Some content in this message has been reported as abusive by Facebook users.

Now few users are able to post comment and everyone is able to reply to their comments, however, admins and many other users are not able to post comments. 
I get many emails regarding this issue. Tried contacting facebook 4 days ago, no response yet.

Have anyone experienced this issue ? Have you found any solution ?

I did some search, saw very few forum posts relevant, all of them unanswered.

The blog runs on wordpress. Everything used to work fine few days ago. The blog contains no spam, duplicate content or anything as such, its just news. No links or words that might trigger profanity censors were included. Even simple comments like "test" doesn't work.

UPDATE: The issue is fixed. Looks like the problem was with facebook, I didn't do anything special to solve it.

Comment: sure you're using the new plugin? (without the **xid**="example.com") try using the [updated](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) comments plugin

Comment: Is there a programming question in there somewhere?

Comment: My code has xid="_post123", depending on the blog post id. Tried entering the url in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/. The comment box displayed there shows the same error when my blog's url is entered.

Comment: @OffBySome, Sorry, I didn't get your point.

Comment: This question shouldn't be closed. The reason for closing is invalid. The answer was very helpful to me and I'm sure will be to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the URL works in the debug tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

If your own domain doesn't appear to be blocked, check the content included on your page, especially any images included from suspicious or free hosting domains.

If it's your own site being blocked, and you believe it's a mistake, there's a form at https://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=block_appeal which sends a note to the spam team

Comment: I tried the url linter before.
I see :
Warning
Required Property Missing og:url is required
Site and URL is not blocked. Most of the traffic is from the site's facebook page itself. The blog doesn't contain images or links to any external hosts.
Very few users are able to post comments (11 comments from about 20k views for the page). Everyone else complaints about the error and the error appears for me too.

Comment: Without seeing the site in question there's no way to know, but if you can share links to the page in question on Facebook.com, it should also be possible to comment on it.

Comment: http://bit.ly/qcw6eb is the site in question.

Comment: Thanks, i'll see if I can see what's happening; the page is Likable and Send-able which I wasn't expecting to work - i can repro the comments plugin not allowing comments to go through

Comment: Try it again; looks like a problem on Facebook's side

Comment: Yea it works now. Looks like a problem on facebook's side.

Comment: @Igy broken link